# "В сайте" или "на сайте"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно?

Comment: К орфоэпии этот вопрос не относится.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428556/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, "на сайте".

Answer (score 2):

Смотря как употреблять. Если считаете кол-во продаж с сайта, то их отсутствие будет означать что дело В САЙТЕ. (юзабилити плохое, поэтому заказывайте сайты в проверенных конторах, например, [тут](http://www.top-7.ru)). 
А если вносятся какие-то правки, то они делаются НА САЙТЕ.

Answer (score 0):

Неужели вы слышали "в сайте"?

Comment: Не, читала.

Answer (score 0):

"В сайте" напоминает "в Украине". Формально правильно, но слух режет. На сайте лучше.