# Зайти в сайт по пароли или зайти на сайт?

Tags: интернет

Гуляю по сайтам в интернете и попался закрытый сайт. Написано - войти или зарегистрироваться. Зарегистрировалась. Ввожу имя и пароль и вхожу,  куда - в сайт или на сайт? Когда зашла вижу, что на сайте творится и знаю, что на сайте, а не в сайте, а вот не знаю куда вошла - в сайт или на сайт?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как грамотно написать - зашла в сайт или на сайт?

Comment: Цитирую V.V. Слово "пароль" в русском языке мужского рода.

Comment: Современное употребления слова "пароль" требует склонения по мужскому роду. Как учитель или рубль. Вариант "по пароли"  очень сильно устарел. Остальное вам написали.

Comment: Ой, добавлю. Тут дело не в грамматическом роде, а именно в типе склонения. Многие существительные на мягкий согласный до середины XIX века склонялись по женской парадигме, оставаясь при этом мужского рода. Это очень древняя, историческая форма склонения, сейчас в русском сохранилась только у существительного **путь**, но в близкородственных славянских присутствует широко.

Comment: Ольга, "придти можно на сайт", - приЙти.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/%d0%92-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **зайти на сайт по паролю/с помощью пароля**.

Можно зайти **на кухню, на террасу, на этаж, на вокзал, на почту, на рынок, на пляж.** В большинстве случаев при использовании предлога "НА" предмет (в том числе отвлечённый, не материальный) воспринимается как **площадка** с расположенными на ней объектами, а не как объём.

И конечно, мы заходим на сайт, на форум, на сервер, на "одноклассников" и т.д., так как это также "площадки", только виртуальные.

Comment: На фейсбук тоже? Почему тогда говорят, что в фейсбуке на страничке мистера "х" ? Сайт это место. Так и и переводится - место. Интернет, как улей с сотами. Такой огромный кусок - соты. Одним словом сайты, как шарики с ячейками в пространстве интернета. Нужно попасть в шарик или на шарик? В соту или на соту? Мне кажется нужно сначала войти в сайт, если он закрыт, чтобы оказаться на сайте. Наверно нужно говорить по разному. В некоторых случаях в сайт или в сайте, а в некоторых случаях на сайт или на сайте. Можно сразу по ссылке попасть на сайт. В сайте могут быть недостатки, чего-то не хватает

Comment: Книга может лежать  на столе  или в шкафу - в реальном пространстве вещей всё понятно. А в виртуальном мире мы только ориентируемся на реальный, когда в речи складываются определенные традиции. В большинстве случаев мы заходим на сайт, потому что так принято говорить, а  "зайти в сайт" не принято говорить. Скорее мы скажем, что у сайта есть недостатки,   но предлог В всё равно употреблять не будем. Что касается "фейсбука", то там традиции  только складываются, предлоги В и НА еще конкурируют друг с другом (НА - площадка, В - объёмное пространство со сложной структурой).

Answer (score 0):

Слово *сайт* заимствовано из английского языка, где оно употребляется с предлогом *на*, потому что его прямое значение *место*. Отсюда и русское употребление и слова, и предлога. Захожу на сайт. Слово "пароль" в русском языке мужского рода.

Comment: Значит на сайтах пишут неправильно - войти и выйти? Нужно придти и уйти ?

Comment: Почему?  Речь о предлоге только. Входите и выходите.

Comment: Как можно зайти на что-то? Зайти можно куда-то, во что-то. Придти можно на сайт, попасть можно на сайт. Взойти можно на трон, на пьедистал и ещё на что-то. Взойти, а не зайти. Не говорят же зашёл на свадьбу или на день рождения. Говорят пришёл на свадьбу, а зашёл в загс, в ресторан, где справляют свадьбу

Comment: Можно зайти на день рождения и в гости. И на сайт.

Comment: И на свадьбу. И на огонёк. Olga Lu, скажите честно, вы живой разговорный русский давно слышали?